# Prevent Entity Framework recreating databases but use existing databases instead

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

Good Day,

I understand so far that EF tries to have the developer work in a code-first paradigm. I am having trouble with my setup at the moment because EF wants to Create a database - and it is being denied. I have already created a database and also changed the generated database connection string to where I want it to connect - and which database to use.

I haven't extensively used EF in my career, but I see a growing need for it over the ADO.NET approach. I have decided to try my hand at it. Here is what I have:

**Connection String**

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=EON-PC\2008;Initial Catalog=Experimental;Integrated Security=true;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

**MVC Models**

```
namespace EFExperiment.Models
{
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Data.Entity;

    [Table("stores")]
    public class Stores
    {
        [Key]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string StoreName { get; set; }

        public string AdminEmail { get; set; }

        public string Url { get; set; }
    }

    public class StoreDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public StoreDbContext()
        {
            //Database.SetInitializer<StoreDbContext>(null); //Tried this - also failed. It didn't try to create a database here
        }

        public DbSet<Stores> Stores { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
namespace EFExperiment.Controllers
{
    using EFExperiment.Models;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web.Mvc;

    public class StoresController : Controller
    {
        private StoreDbContext db = new StoreDbContext();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Stores.ToList());
        }
    }
}
```

***Error:***

```
CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.
```

What confuses me now is - how do you use EF when it is intended to wipe and recreate your DB? Am I missing something here? I would like to read from my actual tables in my DB, along with other CRUD operations - not have it recreate it every time I run my application.

Comment: Look at MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion

Comment: If you have an existing database and want to use it with code first approach, you can use the 'Code First from the database' to generate the required classes and the derived context object. Please refer [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/data/jj200620.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/data/jj200620.aspx)

Comment: Will have a look at that thanks.

Comment: put this code in static constructor of the context class.
`Database.SetInitializer<YourContext>(null);`